# Why doesn't JavaScript have lookbehinds?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind, missing-features

I know there are various work-arounds but it seems strange that a pretty common/helpful regular expression feature isn't available in JavaScript.

Is there any reason for this (performance issues, implementation issues, etc.) or was it not added in the beginning and now it is too late/not needed?

Comment: Why 0.1 + 0.2 isn't 0.3?

Comment: One GOOD reason for why you wouldn't want to implement look behind for your regexp engine is that it makes it non-regular (one reason Perl calls its string matching syntax regex, not regexp). Specifically, look behinds make it impossible to compile the regex into a state machine. If you can't do that then you open yourself up to so-called pathologically slow expressions which engines without look-behinds can avoid. Also, non-state-machine engines tend to be slow even in normal cases. Tcl for example have been benchmarked to be much faster than Perl regex.

Comment: @slebetman Thank you for an actual good reason besides "It just doesn't have it". You should submit your comment as an answer :)

Comment: That's probably better asked at http://esdiscuss.org/.

Answer (score 6):

Because not enough JS developers have marched in to the offices of Netscape then ECMA International with placards reading:

**`We Demand Lookbehinds Now! The Time is Right for Lookbehinds!`**

But it's not too late. You can start a movement, and many people who follow the `regex` tag will be right behind you.

Lead us on, champ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, it just **doesn't**.

Languages can't have all the features available in other languages.

Why doesn't JavaScript have static typing? How come it doesn't support multiple inheritance? It's just  built the way it is.

Comment: At the time of posting my question, I did not realize how many regex flavors there were. That being said, JavaScript has look-aheads so it would seem likely that look-behind would be available as well. I was just wondering if there was any reason other than "because it doesn't" such as performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Why**? The JavaScript regular expression engine clearly does not support lookbehinds.

However, you can simulate the use of lookbehind using the [`XRegExp`](https://gist.github.com/slevithan/2387872) library or with **String**.[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and optional capturing groups.